# How can I make Highcharts zoom working, currently it isn't because _highchartsZoom(e) is not recognize as a function?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm developing a web application which uses highcharts (7.1.1).

I'm facing issues with the zoom that I do not understand.
In this snippet (you cannot run this snippet on stack overflow):

```js
var monoChart = new HighCharts.Chart(getChartObject(chartDiv, trace));
     monoChart._highChartsZoom = monoChart.zoom;
     monoChart._traceData = trace;
     monoChart.zoom = function (e) {
      this._highChartsZoom(e);
      //...
     }.bind(monoChart);
```

When running the program and entering the zoom function, I have the following message: "_highchartsZoom() is not defined".
Surprisingly, when I stop at this code line with the debugger I see that "this" as the value of "H.Chart" and I see an _highChartsZoom function within "this".
I do not understand why I can't use it.
Here is the screenshot : 
[highcharts zoom issue in debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6N3oJ.png)

Furthermore, somewhere else in my code I am using the same function and its working fine.
Here is the snippet of the other code (working - but you cannot run this snippet on stack overflow) :

```js
var chart = new HighCharts.Chart(getChartObject(container, traceData));
    chart._highchartsZoom = chart.zoom;
    chart._traceData = traceData;
    chart.zoom = function (e) {
        this._highchartsZoom(e);
        //...
    }.bind(chart);
```

In the debugger I see no difference between the different "this" in the code line "this._highchartsZoom(e);" They are both "H.Chart" objects.
One is working, not the other.

Help would be very welcome!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in an online code editor? Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rLg0kwp7/

Comment: Hi Wojciech, thanks a lot for your reply and the highchart framework in jsfidle.
Unfortunately it is not that easy for me to reproduce the issue in an online code editor. The code is part of a web app that have thousands of code lines and actually it is not easy to reproduce the bug even in the webapp...
Thank you for your comment.

Comment: So perhaps you are able to send me a package with your project or simplified project with a chart? Without it is hard to say what's the issue.